# a to the power of b - recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am having a hard time understanding the following recursive algorithm in terms of the multiplication operation used in the code.

```
int power(int a, int b) {
    if (b < 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (b == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {           
        return a * power(a, b - 1);
    }
}
```

For inputs (3,7) the result would be 2187. There are total of 6 recursive calls being made:

```
Initial values - 3,7
First recursive call(3,6)
Second recursive call(3,5)
Third recursive call(3,4)
Fourth recursive call(3,3)
Fifth recursive call(3,2)
Sixth recursive call(3,1)
```

Given the following formula:

```
a * power(a, b - 1)
```

is each recursive call multiplying the values of a & b? Which wouldn't make sense, since that would return 81 at the end. I am trying to understand the factors and product in the multiplication operation of each recursive call.

Comment: It's multiplying the values of `a` and the result of calling `power` on `a` and `b - 1`. I'd recommend a piece of paper and pen/cil. Put in a small value, like `(2, 3)` or whatever, and just write down each step: what are the values when `power` is called? Which path through `power` is taken? What's the return value of each call to `power`? Little else will help in understanding recursion better than just "playing computer".

Comment: "is each recursive call multiplying the values of a & b?" -- no.  Each recursive call but the last is multiplying `a` by the value returned by the next call.  The last (in your case) simply returns 1.

Comment: The idea behind this is `a^10 = a * a^9` or `a^b = a * a^b-1`. If you keep "extracting" an `a` from that `a^b`, you will end up with `b-1` multiplications. Thats how you transform an exponential expression into multiplications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `int power(int a, int b)` returns an `int`.
So every time  `return a * power(a, b - 1);` is called, `a` is multiplied by the value returned by `power(a, b - 1)` until you get `b == 0` which returns 1.

At the end you get:

```
return (3 * (3 * (3 * (3 * (3 * (3 * (3 * 1)))))));
```

The value of `b` is the one that stops the recursivity and make you get a result. If `b` wasn't decreased, you'd be in an infinite loop.

So to answer to your question, neither `a` or `b` are multiplied, since all is in the return value. Only `b` is decreased to make the number of loops expected.

I hope this helped you  understand.

Comment: "The value of b is the one that stops the recursivity and make you get a result. If b wasn't decreased, you'd be in an infinite loop." - these 2 lines clarified it for me.

Answer (score 14):

You have to keep in mind that `a` is multiplied by the result of the recursive function call at every step. You might look at it like this:

```
power(3,7)
= 3 * power(3,6)
= 3 * 3 * power(3,5)
= 3 * 3 * 3 * power(3,4)
= 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * power(3,3)
= 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * power(3,2)
= 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * power(3,1)
= 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * power(3,0)
= 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 1 // by definition when b = 0
```

At each step we replace the call to `power(a,b)` with `a * power(a,b-1)`, as the function defines, until we get to `power(3,0)`. Does that help clear up what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

```
 return a * power(a, b - 1);
```

This line has a lot of information to convey. Actually `a` the the base and `b` is the power, which is to be raised to `a`. Now, each time we multiply `a` with the returned value, we are actually raising it to some power.
When return statement is executed for the first time, it stores product of `a` and a call to the power function. During the subsequent calls to power function, the value of `b`, reduces by 1 every time.
Hence in the end, when recursion, unfolds, you get something like this:

```
return a*a*a*a*a*a*a*1
```

Finally in the end, the result is computed and is sent back to the main method. (The calling method)

Answer (score 0):

actually what is happening here, each call is made with a new value of variables, for instance the last call(3* power(3, 0)) would return 3, as (3* 1) = 3, and last call returns the '1' first, and them back tracks,, for last call b = 0, so 1 is returned which is multiplied with 3, which becomes 3

for rest of calls, this 3 would be simply being multiplied each time,,

for fifth call,

it would return value 3 * 3

for forthh it would return,

3 * 9 ,,
and so on

Answer (score 0):

> is each recursive call multiplying the values of a & b? Which wouldn't
>   make sense

This is the wrong assumption. Each recursive call multiplying the values of a & (result of exectuing the same fucntion with a & b-1).

Answer (score 0):

On your last recursive call (`a = 3, b = 0`), you are in this case :

```
} else if (b == 0) {
    return 1;
```

This means, the previous caller (`a = 3, b = 1`) that was on the line `return a * power(a, b - 1);` can be replaced with values `return 3 * power(3, 1 - 1);` -> `return 3 * 1; // 1 being the last recursive call return value`.

Taking the previous one (`a = 3, b = 2`) and doing the same operation

```
return a * power(a, b - 1);
```

-->

```
return 3 * power(3, 2 - 1);
```

-->

```
return 3 * 3 * 1; //the result of the a = 3, b = 1 call
```

And so on...

*a = 3, b = 3*

```
return 3 * 3 * 3 * 1;
```

*a = 3, b = 4*

```
return 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 1;
```

*a = 3, b = 5*

```
return 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 1;
```

*a = 3, b = 6*

```
return 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 1;
```

*a = 3, b = 7*

```
return 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 1;
```